# Wordpress Dequeue Script not working (with jquery)

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to dequeue the following plugin scripts:

```
function afg_enqueue_cbox_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
wp_enqueue_script('afg_colorbox_script', BASE_URL . "/colorbox/jquery.colorbox-min.js" , array('jquery'));
wp_enqueue_script('afg_colorbox_js', BASE_URL . "/colorbox/mycolorbox.js" , array('jquery'));
}
```

I tried adding this in functions.php:

```
add_filter('wp_print_styles', 'remove_mycred', 100);    
function remove_mycred() {
wp_dequeue_script( 'afg_colorbox_script' );
wp_dequeue_script( 'afg_colorbox_js' );
}
```

But it does not work at all - both scripts are still there.
There are other scripts that I have no problems dequeuing - just not those.

I suspect jquery has something to do with my problems?

thanks!

Blaise

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems here, you should use `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook to hook your function to.  Secondly, you will need to go and look at the priority which the author used to enqueue these scripts, and then give your action hook a lower (higher number) priority. Your code should look something like this

```
function remove_mycred() {
  wp_deregister_script( 'afg_colorbox_script' );
  wp_dequeue_script( 'afg_colorbox_script' );
  wp_deregister_script( 'afg_colorbox_js' );
  wp_dequeue_script( 'afg_colorbox_js' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', remove_mycred, 9999 );
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your answer. I tried using exactly your code and then even raising the number to 999999 and it still does not work. These scripts are still there - they're just stubborn :)

Comment: Check my update. Deregister the scripts first, then dequeue them. Should work, untested though

Comment: Many thanks for your efforts - much appreciated. However this still does not work. I still find, looking at the page source the following lines: <script type='text/javascript' src='http://URL/wp-content/plugins/awesome-flickr-gallery-plugin/colorbox/jquery.colorbox-min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://URL/wp-content/plugins/awesome-flickr-gallery-plugin/colorbox/mycolorbox.js'></script>